# How to reuse a part of a 'for loop' in Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way in python to reuse a piece of a 'for loop' in nested 'for loops' ?

I explain what I want to achieve.

I have the following kind of structure, where I iterate over a first range, then in a nested `for` I iterate over a second range.

```py
for a in [A1, A2]:
    do_something_1()

    for b in [B1, B2]:      
        do_something_2()
```

I am in the frame of a Jupyter notebook, and different cells, where each cell is the structure above.

I have to call multiple times this structure, with always the same `do_something_1()`, but different `do_something2()`:

```
# First call
for a in [A1, A2]:
    do_something_1()

    for b in [B1, B2]:      
        do_something_2()
    
# Second call
for a in [A1, A2]:
    do_something_1()

    for b in [B1, B2]:      
        do_something_different_2()
```

Is there a way to 'reuse the logic':

```py
for a in [A1, A2]:
    do_something_1()
```

or even better the logic:

```py
for a in [A1, A2]:
    do_something_1()

    for b in [B1, B2]:
```

So that I just have to "flat-wrap" my `do_something_2()` calls into a generic iterator ?

Comment: You are not providing any of your "for loop data" into the functions - so this looks kind of pointless to me. It would probably be better to understand if this was an actual [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Wrap those loops into a generator function:

```
def some_loops(A1, A2, B1, B2):
    for a in [A1, A2]:
        do_something_1()

        for b in [B1, B2]:
            yield (a, b)

for a, b in some_loops(A1, A2, B1, B2):
    do_something_2()
for a, b in some_loops(A1, A2, B1, B2):
    do_something_different_2()
```

Option 2: Pass the function to call as a parameter:

```
def some_loops(A1, A2, B1, B2, fn):
    for a in [A1, A2]:
        do_something_1()

        for b in [B1, B2]:
            fn()

some_loops(A1, A2, B1, B2, do_something_2)
some_loops(A1, A2, B1, B2, do_something_different_2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always make a string variable that contains the name of the function you want to use inside the re-usable one. For instance, this should work well for your needs:

```
func_to_use = "do_something_2()"

for a in [A1, A2]:
    do_something_1()

    for b in [B1, B2]:      
        eval(func_to_use)
```

The eval function evaluates whatever string you pass inside it.

Comment: `eval` is generally a bad idea.  It often makes code maintenance significantly more difficult than necessary, and it has a number of "gotchas" that can cause bugs.